# How to convert this Apache rewrite rule to Nginx

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, mod-rewrite, rewrite, wordpress

I've been struggling to convert my past Apache rewrite rule to Nginx (also not sure if I'm placing it in the right place so would appreciate if you can tell me where to place it).

Basically, this was the Apache rewrite rule in my `.htaccess` file on WordPress:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule ^/?hosts/(.*)$ /user/$1 [R,L]
</IfModule>
```

As you can see, I'm using this rule in order redirect from
`example.com/hosts/username` to `example.com/user/username`.

I've used this converting tool https://labs.gidix.de/nginx/ and it outputs this conversion:

```
rewrite ^/?hosts/(.*)$ /user/$1 last;
```

However, I tried placing this in Ajenti's (control panel) advanced custom configuration but it's not working.

Comment: That conversion tool does not appear to be very good. (I would recommend not using it.)

Answer (score -1):

Solved it.. I made a typing mistake...

Comment: Although the Nginx `rewrite` you posted above is not the correct conversion of the Apache directive? I would think it should be: `rewrite ^/hosts/(.*)$ /user/$1 redirect;` - but shouldn't that have been a permanent redirect to begin with? (You appear to have logged in as a different user?!)

Comment: If you solved your own problem, that's great! Please post the solution here, though, so others can benefit.